# Delaying writes to SQL Server

Tags: sql, optimization, azure, appfabric

I am working on an app, and need to keep track of how any views a page has. Almost like how SO does it. It is a value used to determine how popular a given page is.

I am concerned that writing to the DB every time a new view needs to be recorded will impact performance. I know this borderline pre-optimization, but I have experienced the problem before. Anyway, the value doesn't need to be real time; it is OK if it is delayed by 10 minutes or so. I was thinking that caching the data, and doing one large write every X minutes should help.

I am running on Windows Azure, so the Appfabric cache is available to me. My original plan was to create some sort of compound key (PostID:UserID), and tag the key with "pageview". Appfabric allows you to get all keys by tag. Thus I could let them build up, and do one bulk insert into my table instead of many small writes. The table looks like this, but is open to change.

```
int PageID | guid userID | DateTime ViewTimeStamp
```

The website would still get the value from the database, writes would just be delayed, make sense?

I [just read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185678.aspx) that the Windows Azure Appfabric cache does not support tag based searches, so it pretty much negates my idea.

My question is, how would you accomplish this? I am new to Azure, so I am not sure what my options are. Is there a way to use the cache without tag based searches? I am just looking for advice on how to delay these writes to SQL.

Comment: I'm not trying to track page hits, and this isn't logging. There are business rules behind what defines a view. How long the user has to be on the page, how long since the same user last visited, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at http://www.apathybutton.com (and the Cloud Cover episode it links to), which talks about a highly scalable way to count things. (It might be overkill for your needs, but hopefully it gives you some options.)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a queue in memory and on a timer drain the queue, collapse the queued items by totaling the counts by page and write in one SQL batch/round trip.  For example, using a TVP you could write the queued totals with one sproc call.

That of course doesn't guarantee the view counts get written since its in memory and latently written but page counts shouldn't be critical data and crashes should be rare.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at how the "diagnostics" feature in Azure works. Not because you would use diagnostics for what you are doing at all, but because it is dealing with a similar problem and may provide some inspiration. I am just about to implement a data auditing feature and I want to log that to table storage so also want to delay and bunch the updates together and I have taken a lot of inspiration from diagnostics.

Now, the way Diagnostics in Azure works is that each role starts a little background "transfer" thread. So, whenever you write any traces then that gets stored in a list in local memory and the background thread will (by default) bunch all the requests up and transfer them to table storage every minute.

In your scenario, I would let each role instance keep track of a count of hits and then use a background thread to update the database every minute or so. 
I would probably use something like a static ConcurrentDictionary (or one hanging off a singleton) on each webrole with each hit incrementing the counter for the page identifier. You'd need to have some thread handling code to allow multiple request to update the same counter in the list. Alternatively, just allow each "hit" to add a new record to a shared thread-safe list.
Then, have a background thread once per minute increment the database with the number of hits per page since last time and reset the local counter to 0 or empty the shared list if you are going with that approach (again, be careful about the multi threading and locking).

The important thing is to make sure your database update is atomic; If you do a read-current-count from the database, increment it and then write it back then you may have two different web role instances doing this at the same time and thus losing one update.

EDIT:
Here is a quick sample of how you *could* go about this.

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // You would put this in your Application_start for the web role
        Thread hitTransfer = new Thread(() => HitCounter.Run(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1))); // You'd probably want the transfer to happen once a minute rather than once a second
       hitTransfer.Start();


        //Testing code - this just simulates various web threads being hit and adding hits to the counter
        RunTestWorkerThreads(5);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        // You would put the following line in your Application shutdown
        HitCounter.StopRunning();  // You could do some cleverer stuff with aborting threads, joining the thread etc but you probably won't need to
        Console.WriteLine("Finished...");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static void RunTestWorkerThreads(int workerCount)
    {
        Thread[] workerThreads = new Thread[workerCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
        {
            workerThreads[i] = new Thread(
                (tagname) =>
                    {
                        Random rnd = new Random();
                        for (int j = 0; j < 300; j++)
                        {
                            HitCounter.LogHit(tagname.ToString());
                            Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(0, 5));
                        }
                    });
            workerThreads[i].Start("TAG" + i);
        }

        foreach (var t in workerThreads)
        {
            t.Join();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("All threads finished...");
    }
}

public static class HitCounter
{
    private static System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<string> hits;
    private static object transferlock = new object();
    private static volatile bool stopRunning = false;

    static HitCounter()
    {
        hits = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    }

    public static void LogHit(string tag)
    {
        hits.Enqueue(tag);
    }

    public static void Run(TimeSpan transferInterval)
    {
        while (!stopRunning)
        {
            Transfer();
            Thread.Sleep(transferInterval);
        }
    }

    public static void StopRunning()
    {
        stopRunning = true;
        Transfer();
    }

    private static void Transfer()
    {
        lock(transferlock)
        {
            var tags = GetPendingTags();
            var hitCounts = from tag in tags
                            group tag by tag
                            into g
                            select new KeyValuePair<string, int>(g.Key, g.Count());
            WriteHits(hitCounts);
        }
    }

    private static void WriteHits(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> hitCounts)
    {
        // NOTE: I don't usually use sql commands directly and have not tested the below
        // The idea is that the update should be atomic so even though you have multiple
        // web servers all issuing similar update commands, potentially at the same time,
        // they should all commit. I do urge you to test this part as I cannot promise this code
        // will work as-is
        //using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("xyz"))
        //{
        //    foreach (var hitCount in hitCounts.OrderBy(h => h.Key))
        //    {
        //        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        //        cmd.CommandText = "update hits set count = count + @count where tag = @tag";
        //        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", hitCount.Value);
        //        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tag", hitCount.Key);
        //        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //    }
        //}

        Console.WriteLine("Writing....");
        foreach (var hitCount in hitCounts.OrderBy(h => h.Key))
        {

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}\t{1}", hitCount.Key, hitCount.Value));
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetPendingTags()
    {
        List<string> hitlist = new List<string>();
        var currentCount = hits.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentCount; i++)
        {
            string tag = null;
            if (hits.TryDequeue(out tag))
            {
                hitlist.Add(tag);
            }
        }
        return hitlist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, does anyone know why the code sample doesn't "prettify"? What am i doing wrong?